# Returning array of user id from eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get all ids of users from my users table. Is there an eloquent way to do it? I have done it using a for loop but I wish to know if there is an laravel way to do it.

Comment: $users->pluck('id')->toArray();

Comment: Thanks Rutviy Kothari. Exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve a collection of object in your model to retrieve only certain attribute of each object in the collection you can use the `pluck` method which can take a single string or an array with the name of property you want to retrieve

```
$users = User::all()->pluck('id');
$users = User::all()->pluck(['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone seeing this years later, It might not be idea to delete id from table, but you can hide it from being returned when you fetch the model.

`protected $hidden = ['id'];`

In your model to hide id (or other fields) from being returned.

If your reason for wanting to delete ID is because you have UUID, i recommend having both and only use UUID for external params, but by far IDs are still faster than UUID especially with large datasets.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115766/should-i-use-uuid-as-well-as-id